# Spring: how to inject field with annotations

Tags: java, xml, spring, swing, annotations

I have class inherit JFrame.

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame {
    public void init() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(new Dimension(600, 400));

        setVisible(true);
        setState(Frame.NORMAL);
        show();
    }
}
```

Spring config for this bean

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN" 
          "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">
<beans>
  <bean id="mainFrame" class="todo.ui.MainFrame" init-method="init">
  </bean>
</beans>
```

class JFrame have private field title.  Title set from xml config

```
<bean id="mainFrame" class="todo.ui.MainFrame" init-method="init">
    <property name="title">
      <value>My To Do List</value>
    </property>
  </bean>
```

How to inject private field with annotation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use @Value annotation:

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame {

  @Value("my title")
  private String title;
```

or if the value is some dynamic variable then you use:

```
@Value("#{beanA.title}")
  private String title;
```

**Update**

If you have to set to the parent then:

```
      @Value("my title")
      @Override
      public void setTitle(String title){
         super.setTitle(title);
      }
```

Comment: Java Swing has JFrame class. I inherit from JFrame, accordingly can not modify the code JFrame.